# Multiple Bar charts with fixed y-axis to highlight the different as shown in fig

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

[image: 4 diff. bar charts need y-axis fixed]

I looking any chart library which has configuration for custom y-axis values. I want to customize the y-axis like ( 0 to 3). I seen D3 and other chart libraries, the Y-axis automatically generates the values. I my design there is only one filed and on one for compare on the x-axis.

Which chart library is most suited for this condition to make this happen. If any example already on google, please share...

Comment: So you saying that you bar chart has a single bar to be shown on x axis and y axis should always grow from o to 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a D3 solution then you can refer my fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/7ftuumv4/2/

code:

```
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
},
width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
//specify data here
data = [{letter: "1", value: 1.3}]
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    ;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
//as you have a fixed x axis value and single data
x.domain([data[0].letter]);
//as you have a fixed range for y axis
y.domain([0, 3]);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Value");
//make the bar chart
  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });
```

Comment: It's Awesome, You made my day!

Comment: Hi Cyril, just one question can you have any solution for a label that is data value (1.3) which i can show above the blue bar as a black text?

Comment: I have added a text to bar code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/7ftuumv4/5/
also added comments in the code.